# pipeline delimiter issue having constraints

Tags: csv, pipeline

I need a code or a program to edit a csv-file where the following conditions should hold:

1. The no. of pipes `|` in each row / line should be 14
2. If 14 pipes are not present the there must be the data which has moved to the following lines. So I need to trim those lines and merge them with the previous line to ensure having 14 pipes.

---

Sample data from csv-file (added due to comments):

- Correct line:

  ```
  ab|bfgc|cd|gfdgde|ef|fg|gh|hi|jdsfk|kl|lm|mfdgn|nq|ql|df
  ```
- Wrong line:

  ```
  dkflmd|bgbfdsfD|Sfsddf|efdgfdg sdfsd|dfgdf|gfdhdfh|gfdg| sdfs|gdf| sdgdf
  gfdgedf|dfy|
  ```

Some of the data in the first line of the wrong code has been shifted to the next line so I need a program which can trim from the next line and append to the previous line.

Comment: What do you have so far? Could you please provide a short snippet of your csv-file? Please think about which programming language you want to use and add the appropirate tag additionally.

Comment: any programming language will be okay for me..

Comment: name|class|section|address <br/> phone no.|<br/>| remarks...

Comment: i just want an automated code so that it will check if 14 pipelines are not there in a single row then it will delete from the next line and add it to the previous row so that 14 pipelines should be there in a single row.

Comment: Please edit your question and append a short, but significant snippet of your input csv-file containing 'correct' and 'incorrect' lines (lines with 14 pipes and lines without).

Comment: So, after your question is somehow complete, what have you done so far? Did you decided which programming language you want to use?

Comment: python will be okay for me

Comment: I havent done anything so far. I am totally new to this coding world and working as an intern I have do this task. Anyone pls help me if possible...

Comment: Since SO is not a code-writing platform, you should first try something yourself. You can do what you need using Python. As a starting point I would suggest to read something about [file-handling](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [csv-files](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) and [strings](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Comment: thanks a lot.. will try and let u know